# why positions not woking sql

Tags: php, sql

My code below works fine but it does not print the result in **descending** order of overall marks. It rather arranges it in order of the student ID.

I have the code that arranges the students position. It works for one year value but when there are more than one year to account for, it does not print the result in descending order...

Below is the code that joins the marks table to the student table:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT  student_id, term, academic_year, classform_name, @prev:=@cur, @cur:=overall, @curRank := IF(@prev= @cur, @curRank, @curRank + @i ) AS classPosition, IF(@prev<> overall, @i:=1, @i:=@i+1) AS counter
FROM (SELECT m.*, SUM(total_marks) AS overall
    FROM marks m
    WHERE classform_name = ? AND term = ? AND academic_year = ? 
    GROUP BY m.student_id
    ORDER BY overall DESC
) AS n 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT  @i:=0, @curRank := 0, @prev:=NULL, @cur:=NULL ) AS q 
) AS completeRankings 
  JOIN studentstable ON completeRankings.student_id=studentstable.student_id ;
```

Comment: Why don't you add an `ORDER BY` after the end of the `SELECT`.

Comment: In the last statement try ORDER BY n desc.
JOIN studentstable ON completeRankings.student_id=studentstable.student_id _ORDER BY n DESC_

Comment: i have tried what you guys said but it did not work. incorrect query.

Comment: my query seems to be working on my PC (localhost ,mysql server) but not working on my online hosting (phpmyadmin)

Comment: I've used JavaScript dataTables to solve it. I reorder the records from highest score to lowest

Answer (score 0):

I've used JavaScript dataTables to solve it. I reorder the records from highest score to lowest